# WaitHandle.WaitAll and ManualResetEvent.Set() - what should be first?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a question about working of WaitHandle.WaitAll, and would appreciate any help.

Let's assume I have such situation: the Parent thread is opening couple of Child Threads and must wait with 'doing other stuff' until child threads finish their work.

I use WaitHandle.WaitAll and would like to stay with this method. (NO Thread.Join etc, please :) )

```
ManualResetEvent[] events = new ManualResetEvent[list.Count];

foreach (string row in list)
{
    events[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);                

    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoSomething));
    thread.Start(events[i]); // start child thread

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000000);

    i++;
}

WaitHandle.WaitAll(events); // wait for child threads finish their work
...
...


private DoSomething(object sth)
{
// some stuff that executes only 1 second
ManualResetEvent.Set()
}
```

So situation for the first newly started child-thread would be that the calling of ManualResetEvent.Set() is BEFORE calling WaitHandle.WaitAll(events) in the Parent thread. Because loop which opens new child threads has some long timeout.

**So my question, wouldn't be such time-line a problem?
Shouldn't be WaitHandle.WaitAll called before calling the ManualResetEvent.Set()?**

Comment: Instead of using `ManualResetEvent`s and `Thread`s, it sounds like it would be better if you used `Task`s and `Task.WaitAll()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not matter. The wait returns when all events are signaled (set) - whether or not that happened before or after wait was called.

Answer (score 3):

As it was said, it does not matter, however, you should consider using the [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class for that kind of things.

It also allows you to run your tasks either simultaneously or consequentially.

Your code then will be only this:

```
Task.WaitAll(
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); }),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); })
    );
```

Comment: svick and AgentFire, thanks for suggestion. Are there some performance benefits under you suggestions ? In what Tasks are better than Threads ? I don't know does it matters, but my Child threads do some 'hard, long CPU and DB work', and the Parent thread only creates them and can't go farther.

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit...but using Parallel was a lot easier than remembering how to use MREs and WaitHandles.